# How to prohibit P2P GO to accept the other peer(second client) connect?

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct

I'm trying to create a P2P connection(group) it only has one owner and one client on android device.

The reason is that if my GO device accepts a second peer connect(just pressed the invited windows), it will receive the P2P CONNECTION CHANGED event(disconnection). I cannot distinguish between the normal P2P disconnection event and this situation.

My first solution is too ignore all connect/disconnect events after the first connection, but it will cause others site effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution.

We can use the **WifiP2pGroup** to check if the GO and peer exist really when we receive the disconnection event.

It cannot find GO or any peer when we receive the real p2p disconnect event, and vice versa.

example:

```
else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
...
WifiP2pGroup p2pGroup = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_GROUP);
...
if ( p2pGroup != null ) {
    if ( p2pGroup.getOwner() != null ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Go address: " + p2pGroup.getOwner().deviceAddress);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "p2pGroup getOwner = null");
        return false;
    }

    Collection<WifiP2pDevice> peerList = p2pGroup.getClientList();
    ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice> list = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>(peerList);

    Log.d(TAG, "p2pGroup list size = " + list.size());
    if ( list.size() <= 0 ) { 
        return false;
    }

    ///*
    String host = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    host = list.get(i).deviceAddress;
    Log.d(TAG, "peer #" + i + " address: " + host);
    }
    //*/
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "p2pGroup = null");
            return false;
    }
```

If I have any misunderstanding, please tell me.
Thanks for reading.